# PowerShell: replacing NUL in large file not working

Tags: r, powershell

I have a huge (39 GB) text file that I eventually need to read into R as a pipe-delimited file. However, there are lots of NUL characters `\0` that do not read in R. I'm trying to replace them in PowerShell beforehand.

PowerShell code:

```
Get-Content file.txt | foreach { $_ -replace '\\0' } | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file_NEW.txt
```

I thought this worked but when I try to read the new file in R, `\0` characters appear in the string and I get this error:

```
Error in vroom_(file, delim = delim %||% col_types$delim, col_names = col_names, : 
  embedded nul in string: '||MORALES BELINDA F TRUST||\0||\0|0||PT||||33.824049|-118.192053||3655||N|WESTON|PL|||LONG BEACH|CA|908073855|C033||3655||N|WESTON|PL|||LONG BEACH|CA|908073855|C033|20111117|988||||||||20111027|20111110|TR|2|1527575||KINECTA FCU|KINECTA FCU|||MANHATTAN BEACH|CA|90266|047978|LAWYERS TITLE|03003|232000.00|20111027||CNV|TR|Y|10|20211201|||D|BGJT|V||115|21||0|0||0|||||Y|Y||\r\n06037|5054001029|5054-001-029|1|\0||BONILLA ...
```

Why are there still NULs in the file? ANY help appreciated! Especially because these functions take so long to run. Please, I'm just trying to read this huge file.

Just in case there is an error in the R code, note it is taken directly from [this post](https://rpubs.com/FelipeMonroy/591813) using the `vroom` and `arrow` packages to read then create parquet files.

Comment: PoSh does not see `\0` as `$Null`. the special char for that is "backtick" and "0".

Comment: @Lee_Dailey True, but `-replace` expects a regex, and backslash is used there.

Comment: @vonPryz - try it with backtick-zero in double quotes. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [vonPryz' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296931/45375) shows the immediate problem with your `-replace` operation: in a *single*-quoted PowerShell string (`'...'`), `\` chars. do *not* need escaping as `\\` in order to be passed *verbatim* to the .NET regex engine that the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) uses behind the scenes.

  - Thus, `'\0'`, when passed to the .NET regex engine from PowerShell, is sufficient to represent a `NUL` character (a Unicode character whose [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) is `0`); alternatively, you could use `` "`0" ``, a *double*-quoted, [*expandable* PowerShell string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), in which `` ` `` serves as the [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters).
- [r2evans' helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296944/45375) shows an alternative solution via the Windows ports of standard Unix utilities that come with the optional [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) download, where piping the input file to
  `tr -d '\0'` may offer the fastest solution, if both the input and the output file use the same character encoding.

In the realm of PowerShell, using `Get-Content` with its default *line-by-line* processing with such a large input file would take too long in practice.

While direct use of .NET APIs may offer the ultimately fastest solution, using [`Get-Content`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/)'s
`-ReadCount` parameter offers a simpler, more PowerShell-idiomatic solution:

```
Get-Content -ReadCount 1e6 file.txt | foreach { $_ -replace '\0' } | 
  Out-File -Encoding UTF8 file_NEW.txt
```

`-ReadCount 1e6` reads 1 million lines (`1e6` uses [exponential notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), i.e. `10` to the power of `6`) *at once* and passes them as an *array* to the [`ForEach-Object`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet (one of whose built-in aliases is `foreach`); since the `-replace` operator is capable of operating on an *array* of values as its LHS, the `NUL` substitution can be performed on all elements of the array at once.

Depending on how many bytes make up the average line in your input file, you can adjust this number upward, if you have more memory available, or downward, if you have less. The higher the number you can use, the faster the command will complete.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that doubling the backslash, `\\`, means that the backspace is escaped. Instead of looking at NUL (0x00), you are looking literally `\0` - two characters.

The correct syntax would be like so,

```
-replace '\0'
```

That being said, processing a large file can be done smarter a way. A fast way would be to process, say, 10 000 lines a time. See [earlier an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59409760/503046) about how to process a file in blocks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know powershell enough to fix that, but you can use `sed` or `tr` to replace the nuls in the files. The `tr` and `sed` utilities are available by default on most (all?) unix-like OSes including macos. For windows, they are included in Rtools35 and Rtools40.

If you do not find it with `Sys.which("tr")`, then you may need to include the full path to the respective utility. Assuming Rtools is installed on the root `c:/`, then something like

- Rtools35: `c:/Rtools/bin/tr.exe`
- Rtools40: `c:/Rtools40/usr/bin/tr.exe`

They are also included in [Git-for-Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) as `/usr/bin/tr.exe` and `/usr/bin/sed.exe` within git-bash. (On the file-system, they are likely under `c:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/`.)

(Same locations for `sed`.)

I should note that I'm doing this through R's `system2` as a *convenience* only. If you're comfortable enough on the bash command line, then this is just as easy to perform there instead.

### data generation

I don't know where the nuls are in your file, so I'll assume that they are record (line) terminators. That is, in most files you'll see each line ending with `\n` or `\r\n`, but for this example I'll replace the `\n` with `\0` (nul).

```r
charToRaw("a|b\nhello|world")
#  [1] 61 7c 62 0a 68 65 6c 6c 6f 7c 77 6f 72 6c 64
ch <- charToRaw("a|b\nhello|world")
ch[ch == charToRaw("\n")] <- as.raw(0)
ch
#  [1] 61 7c 62 00 68 65 6c 6c 6f 7c 77 6f 72 6c 64
writeBin(ch, "raw.txt")
readLines("raw.txt")
# Warning in readLines("raw.txt") :
#   line 1 appears to contain an embedded nul
# Warning in readLines("raw.txt") :
#   incomplete final line found on 'raw.txt'
# [1] "a|b"
```

The nul is a problem (as intended), so we don't see anything after the embedded nul.

### tr

`tr` doesn't like doing things in place, so this takes as input the original file and generates a new file. If file-size and disk space is a concern, then perhaps `sed` would be preferred.

```r
system2("tr", c("\\0", "\\n"), stdin = "raw.txt", stdout = "raw2.txt")
readLines("raw2.txt")
# Warning in readLines("raw2.txt") :
#   incomplete final line found on 'raw2.txt'
# [1] "a|b"         "hello|world"
```

(That warning is safe to ignore here.)

### sed

`sed` can optionally work *in-place* with the `-i` argument. (Without it, it can operate the same as `tr`: generate a new file based on the original.)

```r
system2("sed", c("-i", "s/\\x0/\\n/g", "raw.txt"))
readLines("raw.txt")
# Warning in readLines("raw.txt") :
#   incomplete final line found on 'raw.txt'
# [1] "a|b"         "hello|world"
```

(That warning is safe to ignore here.)

### other than record-terminator

If the nul is not the record terminator (`\n`-like) character, than you have some options:

1. Replace the `\0` character with something meaning, such as `Z` (stupid, but you get the point). This should use the above commands as-is, replacing the `\\n` with your character of choice. (`tr` will require a single-character, `sed` can replace it with multiple characters if you like.)
2. Delete the `\0` completely, in which case you can use `tr -d '\0'` and `sed -i -e 's/\x0//g'` (translated into R's `system2` calls above).